# iOS app using no nibs, having trouble getting off the ground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management, viewcontroller

More and more I see the benefit of creating all views in code and am hoping to switch over completely to this dev style.. and as the title suggests i'm having some minor complications. As usual, i'm sure it's something i'm just barely overlooking. Take a look at my code, might you offer a suggestion? ARC is enabled.

What happens is the `-(id)init;` method returns nil when I check for it in the app delegate and I can't seem to figure out why... the `self = [super init];` call always seems to work, but not in this case.

**main.m**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([BCAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

in **BCAppDelegate.m**:

```
@implementation BCAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    BCViewController *bcv = [[BCViewController alloc] init];

    if (bcv == nil) { printf("it's nil\n"); }

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [bcv setView:view];

    [self.window setRootViewController:bcv];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**BCViewController.h**:

```
@interface BCViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    /*some IVARS*/
}

-(id)init;

@end
```

in **BCViewController.m**:

```
@implementation BCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil { return nil; }

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    /* No Code yet */
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that `initWithNibName:bundle:` method you just wrote. You should see something interesting.

Comment: There is no need to implement `initWithNibName:bundle:` at all. I do everything in code and I don't have that method in any of my view controllers.

Comment: Why are you creating the view for the view controller in the app delegate? Let the view controller handle its own view. That's its job.  Also, do not leave `loadView` as you have it. I almost never implement it myself. But having an empty implementation prevents the view controller from creating its own view.

Comment: There is a [terrible quality, great video](http://vimeo.com/3363949) that describes how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil { 
>      return nil; 
> }
> ```

Don't do that. This is the designated initializer of UIViewController. You're breaking this class's functionality. Return the result of calling `super` (possibly with some additional initializations) or don't implement this method at all.

To generate a view controller's view entirely in code, implement `loadView`. That's all. Again, do not implement it empty the way you are doing! If you implement `loadView` at all, you *must* create a UIView and set `self.view` to it.

Read, read, read the documentation! It tells you what your responsibilities are. Read and obey. Work with and for the framework, don't attack or subvert the framework.

Here's the part of my book showing how to get an app started with a view controller and no nib:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_manual_view

Comment: I first returned [super init] and it threw the thread in to an infinite loop, so I removed this method all together and the problem is solved. Thanks! Why is this the case?

Comment: I chose to keep the override the other init method because I wanted to remove the ability of even using a nib. I must have missed something when I read through the documentation.

Comment: `-[super init]` calls `-initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil`, of course it's recursing